# Words/phrases for work progress

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

This might be a dumb question and I'm not sure if I should move this to ELL but I would like to know what words/phrases we could use - preferably a single word - for work progress that is behind schedule / on schedule / or ahead of schedule.

Not being a native speaker, all I can think of are the following ones:

> The project is ***lagging behind***.
>
> The project is ***on track***.
>
> The project is ***ahead of our schedule***.

What else could we use in place of the bolded phrases? (Hope they are grammatically right. :D)

Comment: Single words?  *Late, early, nominal.*  I'd usually say *on-time* for the latter, but you specified one word.

Answer (score 1):

> The project is [ **behind schedule** | **ahead of schedule** ].
>
> The project is [ **on track** | **is running to plan** | **is running to schedule**].
>
> Progress has been **just as planned**.
>
> Progress has been [**slower** | **faster**] **than planned**.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

> The project is **behind schedule**.
>
> The project **continues on** (or **according to**) **schedule**.
>
> The project is **ahead of schedule**.

Definitions:

> ahead of (or behind) schedule: earlier (or later) than planned or expected

([Oxford American Dictionary](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/ahead-of-or-behind-schedule?q=behind%20schedule))

> on schedule: On time; **as planned or expected**.

([Oxford American Dictionary](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/on-or-according-to-schedule?q=on%20schedule))